# Determine whether a KVO observed change should be animated in MVC

Tags: objective-c, model-view-controller, key-value-observing

(iOS 5, XCode 4.4)

I have a controller (say, C1) that modifies the model which is observed using KVO by a second controller (C2), which manages a view based on the model (I simplified the situation for purposes of this discussion). Now the problem is that sometimes, the changes need to be animated, and sometimes, they don't. However, C2 has no way of telling which case it is dealing with, since it only just listens to the KVO notifications.

Is there a generally accepted solution for this, or does anyone have a good proposal? Am I setting it up wrong? I could let C1 instruct C2 but wouldn't that defeat the purpose of the KVO?

Thanks in advance,
Patrick

Comment: Can you define exactly when you want changes to be animated? What does this depend on?

Comment: It somewhat arbitrarily depends on user input, which is handled by C1.

Answer (score 0):

Not that i know ios5 or KVO but why don't you add a parameter to the model?

```
Model.animated=(true:false)?
```

Comment: Whether a change is animated is a view or controller issue and shouldn't be on the model in MVC, the model should be kept independent of how it is displayed (at least in my understanding of it).